# What's wrong with this code? It only run once

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Test2 < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

  def test_2
    browser =Watir::Browser.new :firefox
    browser.goto 'http://gw03.nextix.org/login'
    accept_next_alert=true

    browser.text_field(:name, "username").clear
    browser.text_field(:name, "username").send_keys "hubeunice"
    browser.text_field(:name, "password").clear
    browser.text_field(:name, "password").send_keys "test1"
    browser.text_field(:name, "login").click
    browser.text_field(:name, "password").clear
    browser.text_field(:name, "password").send_keys "test2"
    browser.text_field(:name, "login").click
    browser.text_field(:name, "username").clear
    browser.text_field(:name, "username").send_keys "admin"
    browser.text_field(:name, "password").clear
    browser.text_field(:name, "password").send_keys "admin"
    browser.text_field(:name, "login").click
    browser.text_field(:link, "Dashboard").click
    browser.text_field(:link, "Customers").click
    browser.text_field(:css, "button.btn.btn-add").click
    browser.text_field(:id, "customer_name").click
    browser.text_field(:id, "customer_name").clear
    browser.text_field(:id, "customer_name").send_keys "ping"
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "(//button[@type='button'])[9]").click
    browser.text_field(:link, "Sub-D").click
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "(//button[@type='button'])[7]").click
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "//form[@id='customer-form']/fieldset/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/span").click
    browser.text_field(:id, "unit_bldg").clear
    browser.text_field(:id, "unit_bldg").send_keys "123"
    browser.text_field(:id, "street").clear
    browser.text_field(:id, "street").send_keys "ljd"
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "(//button[@type='button'])[13]").click
    browser.text_field(:link, "REGION VII").click
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "(//button[@type='button'])[12]").click
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "//form[@id='customer-form']/fieldset/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[4]/a/span").click
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "(//button[@type='button'])[14]").click
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "//form[@id='customer-form']/fieldset/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[9]/a/span").click
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "(//button[@type='button'])[15]").click
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "//form[@id='customer-form']/fieldset/div[2]/div[7]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[10]/a/span").click
    browser.text_field(:id, "minimum_load_account").clear
    browser.text_field(:id, "minimum_load_account").send_keys "12"
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "(//button[@type='button'])[18]").click
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "//form[@id='customer-form']/fieldset/div[4]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a/span").click
    browser.text_field(:id, "daily_load_limit").clear
    browser.text_field(:id, "daily_load_limit").send_keys "12"
    browser.text_field(:id, "no_frequency").click
    browser.text_field(:css, "div.col-xs-2.col-xs-offset-4 > div.form-group > div.pull-left.label-wrapper > div.checkbox > label > input[name=\"frequency_visit[]\"]").click
    browser.text_field(:xpath, "(//input[@name='frequency_visit[]'])[4]").click
    browser.text_field(:css, "button.btn.btn-modal-submit").click
    browser.text_field(:link, "Logout").click
    browser.text_field(:css, "button.btn.btn-logout-yes").click
    browser.text_field(:css, "button.btn.btn-logout-yes").click
  end

  def element_present?(how, what)
    text_field(how, what)
    true
  rescue Watir::Browser::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
  end

  def alert_present?()
    switch_to.alert
    true
  rescue Watir::Browser::Error::NoAlertPresentError
    false
  end

  def verify(&blk)
    yield
  rescue MiniTest::Unit::AssertionFailedError => ex
    @verification_errors << ex
  end

  def close_alert_and_get_its_text(how, what)
    alert = switch_to().alert()
    alert_text = alert.text
    if (@accept_next_alert) then
      alert.accept()
    else
      alert.dismiss()
    end
    alert_text
  ensure
    @accept_next_alert = true
  end
end

init1=Test2
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What is it actually doing?

Comment: @yellowantphil : yes but it has an error and i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @yellowantphil
C:\Ruby193>ruby test2.rb

  1) Error:
Test2#test_2:
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:name
=>"login", :tag_name=>"input or textarea", :type=>"(any text type)"}
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriv
er/elements/element.rb:513:in `assert_exists'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriv
er/elements/element.rb:119:in `click'
    test2.rb:15:in `test_2'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

C:\Ruby193>^A

Comment: If you edit your post with that information, rather than adding it as a comment, more people will see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use     `@browser.button(:name => 'login').click` rather than

```
@browser.text_field(:name => 'login').click
```

And if you have doubt what element are you going to use, you can inspect element or try to use Firebug 2.0.8 to make it easier.